# 405 Error Accessing File

Tags: php, iis-7, http-status-code-405

I'm running PHP on an IIS server. I'm trying to access a pdf file that is in a folder that is linked into the web directory with a symbolic link. It appears that the url is directing to the correct location but I'm getting a 405 error. Any ideas? It does work if I load it into an iframe (it was set up like that originally, I'm trying to make it load in a new window).

Answer (score 2):

`405 Method Not Allowed`. This means that you are trying to access a resource using a method (`GET`, `POST` etc) that it does not support.

I suggest monitoring or logging network activity to see what kind of request is being sent. Most likely it has to be `GET` when accessing a PDF, and perhaps, for some reason, you're sending a `POST`.